Getting "Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04" screen in gui after upgrading, CLI interface still authenticates, all files seem intact
I am an experienced Windows administrator who started a new job where I inherited a Ubuntu environment with an Ubuntu file server, an Ubuntu authentication server, and about 75 Ubuntu workstations, all with very little documentation.  Everything was on 18.04 LTS.
We are trying to get everything updated to 20.04 LTS, then 22.04 LTS.  Most machines updated without issues.
However, I have about 6 random machines that updated to 20.04 without issue.  However when we tried to update to 22.04 LTS, the update appeared to complete normally but when we rebooted (with no external media attached) the gui displays the "Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04" screen and wants someone to configure the location, time zone, and first user.
Yet, if I log into the machine using SSH or I use CTRL-alt-F2 to switch to cli, my credentials work normally and the user files are still there.  Everything from the command line appears to be working normally.  Ctrl-alt-F1 goes back to the gui that thinks it needs configured.
Any ideas what would cause this split personality and how to get the gui back in sync with the cli?

Do you happen to have the boot media (USB stick or whatever) for 22.04 attached?

No, this was updated from the internet repository.
